# angularfire2 database list multiple update at once

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I need to update a database list multiple times as shown below.

Is there a more efficient way than calling `database.list('path/to/').update(key,value)` multiple times? Does it have an effect on the performance?

This is what I'm currently doing:

```js
var newNode = {};
newNode[appointmentUid] = true;

this.database.list('/appointment/users').update(userId, newNode);
this.database.list('/appointment/users').update(worker_uid, newNode);
this.database.list('/appointment/users').update(client_uid, newNode);
this.database.list('/appointment/users').update(patient_uid, newNode);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `ref ... update` with the object notation to update multiple elements at once. Ex [from the doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields) :

```
let newValues = {
  "userId": newNode,
  "worker_uid": newNode,
  "client_uid": newNode,
  "patient_uid": newNode,
};

firebase.database().ref('path/to').update(newValues);
```

Comment: Thanks @Miam84, but I think there is not that option in Angularfire2

Comment: The questioner has asked multiple updates for AngularFire2 and not the firebase JS sdk.